# class oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.AdfFacesContextImpl....adf-faces-impl-1013.jar

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I am getting this error when I execute:

> Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: class oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.AdfFacesContextImpl

and tried and tried in search to download `adf-faces-impl-1013.jar` but unable to find the jar.

Can any one help me where can I download this jar file?

Comment: jdeveloper 11g-version 11.1.1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

User, without your exact jdev version nobody can help.

Not sure why you use the class in the "adf-faces-impl-1013.jar"? 
The class is part of the specific jdev installation and normally is part of /jlib/adf-faces-impl.jar

However, the fact that you get the error points to a improper configuration of your application or workspace.